# How can I get information about X:bind from code?

Tags: xaml, reflection, uwp

In universal windows apps, a new form of binding is available. Lets use this example:

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind TextContent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

where `TextContent` is a simple dependency property in the same user control / or the same page. Now, the xaml compiler generates the binding by creating some `.cs` files in the output directory.

As the bininding is compiled into the resulting application, I want to know if there is there a way to gather information about the binding from code? Specifically, I'd like to get the property path (`TextContent` in this example) from my own code.

Comment: I've already looked at the generated files and didn't spot some obvious interfaces or strings which encapsulate the binding.It's all hardcoded!

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Just another example: I'm using a base class for a page (code only, without xaml). Therefore I can't call `Bindings.Update()` in the baseclass without any aditional code in each derived page.